# C# Entity Framework - Best practice for verifying that a record will be successfully saved

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I have a part of my code that updates two databases A and B that are used on two different systems. The database A is the primary, thus a record cannot exist in database B without existing in database A.

So I made a quick solution to verify the success of database A, with one minor issue: The primary key column is auto-incremented every time I do the verification, so my ID gets incremented by 2. It doesn't cause any problems but I would like to find a more efficient solution.

```
public void UpdateDatabases(Product model)
{
   bool verify_A = SaveDatabaseA(model, true);

   if(verify_A)
   {
      bool save_B = SaveDatabaseB(model);

      if(save_B)
      {
          bool save_A = SaveDatabaseA(model, false);

          if(save_A)
          {
              //Show notification 
          }
      }
   }
}

public bool SaveDatabaseA(Product model, bool verificationOnly = false)
{
    var result = true;

    try
    {
        using (var entities = new entities())
        {
            using (var dbContextTransaction = entities.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    // Update code here....

                    if (!verificationOnly)
                    {
                        dbContextTransaction.Commit();
                    }

                    dbContextTransaction.Dispose();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                     response = false;
                     dbContextTransaction.Rollback();
                     dbContextTransaction.Dispose();
                     LogErrors(ex, userID);
                }
            }
        }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
        response = false;
        LogErrors(ex, userID);
   }

   return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first call to SaveDatabaseA does all the work but skips committing the transaction. This increments the identity property on your underlying table but since the transaction is not committed, the data is not saved. The second call to SaveDatabaseA commits the transaction so your identity sequence is incremented by 2 for each saved record.